# Set Variable Product Price before adding in WooCommerce order programatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

In Cart, I added a button to create quotation orders. I am using a quantity range pricing plugin so all of my variable products have a wide range of pricing.

Eg. Product A's item cost is **$5** when quantity is below **100**. Item cost is **$3** when quantity is **100** to **199.**

My cart displays the correct item cost and I manage to retrieve each cart item's product price. However, I am unable to set the variation price and add the data into order.

Does anyone knows how can I solve this?

```
        // Now we create the order
            $order = wc_create_order();

        // add products from cart to order
        $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        foreach($items as $item => $values) {

            $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $values['data'], $values, $item );

            $tieredPrice = WC()->cart->get_product_price($_product);

            $product_id = $values['product_id'];

            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            $quantity = (int)$values['quantity'];

            $var_id = $values['variation_id'];

            $variationsArray = array($values['variation']);
            $var_product = new WC_Product_Variation($var_id);
            $var_product->set_variation_price($tieredPrice); //how do I set variation price?

            $order->add_product($var_product, $quantity, $variationsArray);
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cart `$values['data']` is already an instance Of the `WC_Product` object, so for a **product variation** it is directly an instance of the `WC_Product_Variation` object, so this will be simple now.

The `set_variation_price()` method doesn't exist for WC_Product objects, it is `set_price()`…

So your revisited code will be:

```
// Now we create the order
$order = wc_create_order();

// Add products from cart to order
$cart = WC()->cart; // cart object
foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
    $product   = $cart_item['data']; // An instance of the WC_Product object
    $qty = intval($cart_item['quantity']); // The quantity
    $tierced_price = $cart->get_product_price($_product); // your "tierced" price
    $product->set_price( $tierced_price ); // <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  SET THE PRICE
    $args = array( $cart_item['variation'] ); // empty if not a variation

    $order->add_product( $product, $qty, $args );
}
```

This should work

Comment: There is a small problem when I save the quote. The product price is incorrect.

Let say Product A’s $tiered_price is $5 (which is the correct product price). The product price being set is $365. 

I tried to save another product. There is a “36” before the tiered price again. The product price being saved is always $36tieredprice (eg. $3617 with $17 as tiered price).

Comment: @JacintaPhua As `$tierced_price = $cart->get_product_price($_product);` is not really working, you should save the custom price in cart object as a custom field when product is added to cart. Then it could be called easily after in your code without errors. Now this answer is correct regarding your question details and code. You don't give the code that you are using to set this `$tiercedPrice`…

Comment: @JacintaPhua So what about this… you didn't answer my comment.

Comment: Yes, the solution works better! Thank you so much for the help!